# Is there a better way to select tables based on how many rows they have via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking to grab a group of tables that have more than X rows with jQuery. Currently, I'm doing something similar to:

```
    $("table").each(function(){
 if($(this).find("tr").length > x){
  tableArray[tableArray.length] = $(this);
 }
});
```

and then acting on the members of the tableArray.

Is there a better way of getting these tables, perhaps a nice selector I've missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$('table:has(tr:eq('+x+'))');
```

That would only grab tables that have a row `x`.  Note that [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) takes a zero-based index as its parameter, meaning if `x` is 1, tables containing 2 rows or more would be selected.

**EDIT** `:has` is falling over for me, with `:nth-child` and `:eq`.  [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) (the method equivalent of the selector) works though:

```
alert($('table').has("tr:nth-child(2)").length)​
```

Although, note that the parameter passed to `nth-child` is not zero-based like `:eq` is.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/baNAJ/) - alerts the number of tables found with 2 rows or more.

Comment: Strange, but :has doesn't seem to like :eq, 0 is always returned. http://jsfiddle.net/S2EE2/  (never used :has before, so decided to try now)

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: way ahead of you :-)  See my edits and my example http://jsfiddle.net/baNAJ/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using this problem in a Firefox extension, and it seems to contradict what your example shows. Since the .has() selector just goes one descendant down, I think the <tbody> is confusing it. 

It's a shame the :nth-child doesn't work properly with :has, which can go to any child depth. I guess I'll use my current solution.

Comment: @bubbahotep: `.has()` goes through all descendants - *Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element*.  Also, if you check my linked example, those tables have `<tbody>` elements.  Maybe the problem lies elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$("table tr:nth-child(" + (x + 1) + ")").parent();
```

Didn't test it, but should be close. Note, you may need two ".parent()" calls, depending on your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is fine, frankly.

One alternate way would be to use the **[`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** selector in conjunction with **[`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)**: ask jQuery for `$("tbody:has(:nth-child(4)))...`. This says "find all tables whose `tbody` elements have 4 or more children". Since the children of a `tbody` are typically `tr` elements, this will do the trick.